# Python - create additional statements when calling inherited method

Tags: python

Let's say I have this:

```
class Foo:
    ...
    def func():
        return 1+2

class Bar(Foo):
    ...
    def another_func():
        # additional stuff I want to do when my parent's func() is called
```

I don't want to override `func` , but I do want to add some additional statements when it's called. Also, I don't want to change the original `Foo.func`.

Is it even possible? If not, any idea for a workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Do you want to call func and then do other things, or do you want to modify func itself?  Or do you want to pass additional arguments? Or ...?

Comment: Could you be more specific about why you don't want to override `func`?  Usually that's exactly what you'd do, give the subclass a `func` which calls the parent `func` and then does other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `func` function and make the call to parent's `func` from within it. Python has [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) for that purpose:

`super(type[, object-or-type])`

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type.
>   This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class. 
>   The search order is same as that used by getattr() except that the type itself is skipped.

Example:

```
class Foo(object):    
    def func(self):
        print "In parent"

class Bar(Foo):
    def func(self):
        super(Bar, self).func()
        print 'In child'   # Your additonal stuff
```

When you will run the `func` of `Bar` as:

```
b = Bar()
b.func()
```

will print:

```
In parent   #  <-- from Foo.func()
In child    #  <-- from Bar.func()
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no way of doing that, the canonical solution would be to overide func und wrap the original function like so:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    ...
    def func():
        # additional stuff I want to do when my parent's func() is called
        res = super(Bar, self).func()  # super().func() on Py3
         # additional stuff I want to do after my parent's func() is called
        return res
```